# Can't find Db in mongodb while using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The following code, works exactly fine giving the output [image].

```js
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var dbUrl='mongodb://localhost:27017/trial1';

mongoose.connect(dbUrl);

//Creating schema
    var userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
        name:String,
        email:String,
        createdOn:Date
    });


mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
var User=mongoose.model('User');

var userOne=new User({name:'Mike'});
console.log(userOne.name);


mongoose.connection.on('connected',function(){
console.log('mongoose connected to '+dbUrl);
});

mongoose.connection.close(function(){
    console.log('connection closed!!!!');
});
```

But when I try to search for the db in the connection string (ie)trial1, I am not able to find it, The screen shot is as follows. [image]

Also when I say "use trial1" in mongo shell I'm getting the output as per the  following screen shot.[image] Which means the db exists or its been created. 
Why am I not able to see that db??

Comment: Sorry but you are not telling us the whole truth. The connection is **never** closed unless you explicitly call `mongoose.disconnect()` which you must be calling somewhere but not showing this. To the question of *"where is the data?"*, then the code shown does not create any data. MongoDB allocates database and collection namespaces at the time that something is actually inserted and exists. None of the listing shows anything like that happening. Just connecting to a database or collection does not create it by itself. If you called `user1.save(function(err) { })` then there would be data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So yes the answer is in the comment of Blakes and also part of answer from Pio.

You don't see the databases because your Mongoose code does not actually create any user in it. When you instantiate your Model User it will create it in memory but not in the database. To insert your user in the database you must call the method save on your instance like this:

```
var userOne=new User({name:'Mike'});
userOne.save(function(err, user){
  if (!err) {
    console.log('Now my user is saved in the database');
  }
})
```

So if you don't save your user, then in the mongo shell you won't see the databases as it is empty and so does not exists.

Comment: Thanks Julien ... .Since I was able to console.log it , I misunderstood that it got committed in the DB... Thanks again for the clarity....

Answer (score 1):

what user you use to access the db, maybe the user have no auth on the db.
or, your db url should be this: mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/trial1.
thanks.

Answer (score -3):

To display a database with `show dbs` you need to insert at least one document into one of the db's collection. See more [details here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_create_database.htm).

Comment: Really not what is being asked here. The code presented creates no data.

Comment: What do you mean? He said he doesn't see the database. I just answered why didn't he see the database.

Comment: Does not see the database because there is no database. Read the question in full. Nothing has been created.

Comment: Isn't it what I said? He is complaining that he cannot see the db in show dbs. It is because he did not insert anything in it. It does not mean it hasn't been created logically... when you say `use dbname` you have a pointer to the db `dbname` in memory. But in some sense it is not created, at least on disk.

Comment: I cannot find the part where I wrote you can show a db that does not exist. I gave an answer why he does not see the db in `show dbs`. This is exactly the last sentence in his question.